# Replace more than one continuous occurrence of underscore character "_" with the string "blank"

Tags: java, android, string, replace, character

I need to replace more than one continuous repetition of character `_` in any string with the word `blank` such that `This_is a test ___` becomes `This_is a test blank`. If there is only one `_` character, it should not be replaced.

Multiple consecutive underscores need to be replaced by blank so that the word blank will be uttered when the string is read for text to speech in android.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a [Regular Expression](https://www.regexbuddy.com/regex.html). Luckily, there is a method on `String` called [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) that takes a Regular Expression:

```
final String input = "This_is a test ___";
final String output = input.replaceAll("_{2,}", "blank");
System.out.println(output);  // Prints "This_is a test blank"
```

What the expression there means is: "find at least 2 consecutive occurrences of underscore".

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method:

```
String str = "This_ is a ____";
str = str.replaceAll("[_]{2,}", "blank");
```

***Output:***

```
This_ is a blank
```